# <lightning:unsavedChanges > for this tage Can we modified the dom element of popup that comes because of this tag

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is There any we can modify the dom element of popup that comes because of this tag. `<lightning:unsavedChanges>`.

There is one attribute in `<lightning:unsavedChanges>` that is Body where we can pass our component. How we will pass our component in the body?

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome" access="global">
    <lightning:unsavedChanges aura:id="unsaved"
                              onsave="{!c.handleSave}"
                              ondiscard="{!c.handleDiscard}" />
    <lightning:button label="Make Unsaved Changes" onclick="{!c.makeUnsavedChanges}" />
    <lightning:button label="Clear Unsaved Changes" onclick="{!c.clearUnsavedChanges}" />
<aura:component>
```